# Is it possible to minify all bundles except one?

Tags: optimization, webpack, minify, minimize

I've got my webpack optimization configured as follows:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    minimize: false,
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        minSize: 0,
        cacheGroups: {
            config: {
                test: /[\\/]app[\\/]js[\\/]config[\\/]/,
                minSize: 0
            },
            vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name(module) {
                    // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                    // or node_modules/packageName
                    const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

                    // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                    return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                },
            }
        },
    },
},
```

This work perfectly and generates all the bundles I want.
BUT, I don't want the config bundle to be minified. All the other bundles should be minified though. So far I've only found a global setting, minimize: true/false. I there another, more granular way of setting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation about [optimization.minimizer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer) setting and [chunkFilter](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#chunkfilter)
option. You should set a name for `config` chunk. And add something like this to your `optimization` settings:

```
minimizer: [
  new TerserPlugin({
    chunkFilter: (chunk) => {
      if (chunk.name === 'CONFIG CHUNK NAME') {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    },
  }),
],
```

Note that you need to require the plugin: `const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');`.

Comment: Awesomeness, this works! I had read about optimization.minimizer here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer, but I did not think to delve deeper into that to find this https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#chunkfilter.
Thanks a million.